# Why can't I use objects from .dll in my class library?

Tags: c#, class-library

Just created a .dll file that has some methods. And I have a another project with a class library and client application that reference between each other and work fine.

The problem is that I reference the .dll I just created in the class library but cant use the methods that are available in the .dll. (I can see them in the object browser and everything looks fine).

Like when I try:

```
Cache cache = new Cache("blabla");
```

I get:

> The reference i made.Cache' is a namespace but is used like a 'type'.

But when I add reference in the client application (which is a console app). Then I get no problems and can use the methods easily. Why Does is give my problems in the class library ??

any suggestions

Comment: Probably because your namespace also is called `Cache`, or because you're missing a `using` statement. Use a more specific identifier, such as `cache = new YourDllNameSpace.Cache()` to instantiate it.

Comment: Are you including a namespace that ends with `Cache`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a naming conflict with a namespace that is in scope and features the word `Cache` in it, likely at the end (something like `namespace MyCompany.MyNamespace.Cache { }`).

You need to fully qualify the type in-line or untangle the namespaces and use `using` statements at the top:

```
MyNamespace.Cache cache = new MyNamespace.Cache("");
```

Try to follow the [namespace naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to avoid this situation:

> Do not use the same name for a namespace and a class. For example, do
>   not provide both a Debug namespace and a Debug class.

Answer (score 2):

There would be no reason for this unless `Cache` is interpreted as a namespace within the class library. Either fully qualify the class when instantiating:

```
var cache = new SomeNamespace.Cache();
```

Or use an alias to the class:

```
using MyCache = SomeNamespace.Cache;
...
var cache = new MyCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fully qualifying your type:  `MyDllAssembly.Cache cache = new MyDllAssembly.Cache();`